# Is there a combination available between AWS SQS and SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We are planning to use AWS SES with SQS. The idea is to push the email content to SQS then SES fetch the queue item and send the emails. We are using PHP. 
We just want the idea to implement this without hampering the webserver performance.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! This sort of question asking for recommendations is pretty broad and will likely be closed; see more here to narrow your question's scope: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask As for general advice -- SES can't retrieve content from SQS on its own; you need a queue-processing component to read from the queue and prepare a request to SES to send the email. This would ideally be a separate process from your main webserver; a 'queue-processing' web service that can be scaled independent of your main webserver based on factors such as the SQS queue depth.

Comment: Thanks Anthony! Currently we have already implement the SES to sending emails. As I come to understand we need to push the email content to SQS then implement an API which process this queue(Message Polling) and then SES will send the mail.

Comment: Please add those missing details to your question.  State why you need to push email to SQS?  If you jump straight into the services you assume, you might doing things in complicate ways.  e.g. AWS lambda can be trigger to process lots of stuff.

Answer (score 5):

SES cannot fetch stuff from SQS.
You will have to have a compute tier in between (either on EC2 or Lambda or some other server), which could poll the SQS and then call SES.

Scheduled Lambda can be ideal for this use case.

Out of curiosity, who is putting the message in SQS and do tou have any specific use case for putting the message in SQS. Why can't the routine that places the message on SQS, simply call the SES and get the email sent

Comment: I suppose the answer to your last question lies in 'what are the benefits of using SQS?'

Answer (score 1):

Answer is summed up in previous answer but still I want to put a word for it.
Flow that I implemented was like this: Invoking sender lambda of sqs -> sqs queue triggers reciever lambda of ses -> ses sends mail.

The answer to why it is to be done? To avoid bottlenek at SES.
A Lambda function can process items from multiple queues (using one Lambda event source for each queue). You can use the same queue with multiple Lambda functions.

Other ways to maximize throughput of SES given in docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot-throughput-problems.html